# a interesting and simple question about jni

Tags: java-native-interface

env->CallStaticObjectMethod(classId,mid,"jack",4);
told me that java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "L''java/lang/Class;.say(L''java/lang/String;I)L''java/lang/String;"

I don't know where it is wrong ,who can tell me ,please

Comment: You can't pass a C string to a Java method that expects a `java.lang.String` instance. You'll have to create a Java string using `NewStringUTF` or `NewString`.

Comment: thank you for your answer,but this is the code which jmethodID mid = env-> GetStaticMethodID(classId,"say","(Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/lang/String;"); that report an error,I don't know there it is wrong